# How can we validate the URL'S links in java script

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote the code for form field validation in JavaScript,
but it's not working properly as my requirement.

URLs only support:

**http**

**https://**

and **(www.xyz.com , xyz.com ,xyz.co.in )**

My code :

```
var file_url = document.getElementById(url);
if(file_url.value.match(^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$)){
  alert('Please Enter valid Url');
  return false;
}
```

but it does not work as expected

Comment: `^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^.]+\.)+\w{2,3}$`

Comment: You're missing regex delimiters `/.../`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trails i got this one better,I have tried this one working perfectly.I think this one also correct one.

```
if(!file_url.value.match(/(^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/gi)){
                        alert('Please Enter valid Url');
                        return false;
                         }
```

Here is the demo: [Demo of regex](https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/58)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/58